# Cannot get Django-Bootstrap-Toolkit working on my project

Tags: django, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just started to learn Django and Twitter Bootstrap on some project.
I use external links to connect css and js files of bootstrap, but today I found [Django-Bootstrap-Toolkit](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit), so I wonder how to switch my project to it.

project folder:

```
myproject/
     /bootstrap_toolkit/
     /myproject/
     /templates/
     /someapp/
     /manage.py
```

settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'someapp',
'bootstrap_toolkit',
...)
```

templates/base.html

```
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--CSS Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

So, if I'm deleting link tag, all the CSS disappears, so, I wonder what I've done wrong, and my toolkit is not connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap3, according to the documentation you should instead use this package: https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

Regarding the CSS files: I have never used either of those packages but you definitely have to have a link to the bootstrap static files somewhere. So just don't remove the link tag and you're fine!

Comment: Actually, it works already. So, like 'better is enemy to the good'.

Comment: If you look into the example apps of those packages there are also special template tags for loading the bootstrap static files `{% bootstrap_css %}` and `{% bootstrap_javascript %}`. But I'd still prefer to do this manually.